# MongoDB aggregate function is not returning the value of collection joined using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, database, mongodb, aggregate

I needed assistance in order to work out why the aggregate function is not responding the way I'd expect it to respond. This is a RESTful API service I've designed in which I am trying to connect collections with each other. Please note the following:

## **Collection: Season**

```
{
"_id": {
    "$oid": "5c0fc60bfb6fc04dd6ea4e9a"
},
"Season": "1",
"TotalEpisode": "15",
"Name": null,
"Description": "First season with no name for this drama",
"PlayID": "5c0fc4aafb6fc04dd6ea4d81"
}
```

## **Collection: Play**

```
{
"_id": {
    "$oid": "5c0fc4aafb6fc04dd6ea4d81"
},
"Name": "It was the first time",
"Description": "One of the best action heros in the entertainment industry until this day",
"ReleaseDate": "24/12/2010",
"EndingDate": "12/08/2012",
"Category": "Drama"
}
```

## **My implemented code in JavaScript**

```
function getTestLookUp(db, collectionName, response, secondCollectionName){
console.log('First collection name: ' + collectionName + '\n' + 'Second collection name: ' + secondCollectionName);
db.collection(collectionName).aggregate([
    {
        $lookup:
        {
            from: secondCollectionName,
            localField: 'PlayID',
            foreignField: '_id',
            as: 'requestedDetails'
        }
    }
]).toArray((err, res) => {
    if(err){ 
        console.log(err);
    } else {
        console.log(res);
        response.status(200).json({
            'Items': res
        });
    }
});
}
```

## **The response**

```
{
    "Items": [
        {
            "_id": "5c0fc60bfb6fc04dd6ea4e9a",
            "Season": "1",
            "TotalEpisode": "15",
            "Name": null,
            "Description": "First season with no name for this drama",
            "PlayID": "5c0fc4aafb6fc04dd6ea4d81",
            "requestedDetails": []
        }
    ]
}
```

The things I've checked so far: the collection names are accurate, the ID is also accurate as I can search it up on the MLabs search feature. I don't understand as to why this is returning a empty 'requestedDetails' as I hoped it would return the item from the Play collection. 
In addition to this, I would also appreciate if someone can point out how I can join multiple collections instead of 2.
**I welcome any questions regarding this problem.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While still researching for this issue, I accidentally came across a another problem in which someone wrote a comment stating that "you might be comparing a String with ObjectID". This was the cause for this error as I obtain a String variable in return from the database and I am comparing the String variable with the _id which is expecting to see a ObjectID variable to complete the query. Therefore, meaning that my query/lookup is never matching these two variables. 
The only way tackle this issue is to do a conversion (string to ObjectID) and then compare the values. However, since I'm using the version of ^3.1.10 of MongoDB, this functionality is not possible. Will need to update the version to 4.0 to be able to implement this functionality.
In order to rectify this issue, I managed to surround the foreign ID within $iod tags.

## **Before**

```
{
"_id": {
    "$oid": "5c0fc60bfb6fc04dd6ea4e9a"
},
"Season": "1",
"TotalEpisode": "15",
"Name": null,
"Description": "First season with no name for this drama",
"PlayID": "5c0fc4aafb6fc04dd6ea4d81"
}
```

## **After**

```
{
"_id": {
    "$oid": "5c0fc60bfb6fc04dd6ea4e9a"
},
"Season": "1",
"TotalEpisode": "15",
"Name": null,
"Description": "First season with no name for this drama",
"PlayID": {
"$oid": "5c0fc4aafb6fc04dd6ea4d81"
}
}
```

## **Response**

```
{
    "Items": [
        {
            "_id": "5c0fc60bfb6fc04dd6ea4e9a",
            "Season": "1",
            "TotalEpisode": "15",
            "Name": null,
            "Description": "First season with no name for this drama",
            "PlayID": "5c0fc4aafb6fc04dd6ea4d81",
            "Details": [
                {
                    "_id": "5c0fc4aafb6fc04dd6ea4d81",
                    "Name": "It was the first time",
                    "Description": "One of the best action heros in the entertainment industry until this day",
                    "ReleaseDate": "24/12/2010",
                    "EndingDate": "12/08/2012",
                    "Category": "Drama"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```